# SQL Query takes much longer when decreasing the date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which includes a date range.

When I have the date range as "> '2013-05-01'" in the query, I get the results in 188.300 ms. However if I change the date range to "BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-01'" I get the results after 1102312.636 ms. This doesn't make sense to me at all as the 2nd date range includes a lot less data.

Here are the 2 queries and their explains underneath:

```
SELECT 
SUM(quantity)
FROM
transaction_master
INNER JOIN transaction_line_items ON transaction_line_items.link_guid = transaction_master.guid
AND master_code = 'AAL027PU' and item_colour = 'BE'
AND (sale_date  > '2013-05-01')
AND transaction_type = 'POSSALE'
```

Explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/hPtI

```
SELECT 
SUM(quantity)
FROM
transaction_master
INNER JOIN transaction_line_items ON transaction_line_items.link_guid = transaction_master.guid
AND master_code = 'AAL027PU' and item_colour = 'BE'
AND sale_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-01'
AND transaction_type = 'POSSALE'
```

Explain: http://explain.depesz.com/s/WN1

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for including plans with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` without being asked! Your version (`SELECT version()`) would be nice though. Both plans show some pretty bad statistical estimates; does `ANALYZE;` on the database (or the set of involved tables) help any? Also consider increasing the statistics target on ... well, whatever the one is with the bad estimates, it's too hard to deal with "anonymized" plans for me to try to nail it down. Look at the "rows x" column, it should be small; big means bad estimates due to stats issues or planner limitations.

Comment: BTW, the anonymized plans mean we can't compare anything in the plan usefully to anything in the queries you showed above without mess and guesswork. Going in my "too hard" basket.

Comment: @CraigRinger, you were right. The analyze fixed the issue. The planner was mis-estimating the rows. Next time I won't anonymize :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examination of the query plans suggested bad row-count estimates, due to:

- Uneven distributions and low statistics targets;
- Outdated stats  (is autovacuum running often enough?)
- A query planner mis-estimation

First, run `ANALYZE`. If you need to do this by hand, it probably means autovacuum isn't running enough, or you just recently bulk-loaded a table and autovac hasn't kicked off yet.

If that doesn't help, adjust the stats targets for the relevant columns, so analyze samples more rows.

If you still get the same estimates, this may suggest that the planner is mis-estimating the way the inputs will combine. That's harder to deal with; you'd need to report it to pgsql-performance and seek advice there.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions apply to the JOIN statement and I suspect that you should add WHERE clause. Otherwise it looks like server scans all tables for the records with matching condition instead of filter out required records first and then do the join. Of course, simple join using foreign key only will ve much faster. So try this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(quantity)
FROM
transaction_master
INNER JOIN transaction_line_items ON transaction_line_items.link_guid = transaction_master.guid
WHERE
    master_code = 'AAL027PU' and item_colour = 'BE'
AND sale_date BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-08-01'
AND transaction_type = 'POSSALE'
```

Comment: That won't make a difference. Postgres is smart enough to generate the same execution plan.